# asp.net mvc jquery validating dataannotation validations before popup activated on submit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

ok what i am trying to do i have a form which has client side validation. it is working fine

but i need to change it and insert a popup on the button submit(having yes and no, yes confirms and save the record, no cancel it). this is a confirmation popup which will confirm that the user indeed want to update the record.

but the problem is that the validations are not firing on the click of the submit button. it is firing when i press the yes button (which is submit to the controller).

this is my submit button click , basically what i want is the validation to be fired before the popup is loaded. i have the option to do it manually but really don't want to

```
   $("#updatequot").click(function () {
        var url = "/Quotation/EditCheckTerminal/";
        var TerminalId = $("#Terminal").val();
        var nrt = $("#NRT").val();
        var grt = $("#GRT").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { QuotationId: '@ViewBag.Id', Terminal: TerminalId, nrt: nrt, grt: grt },
            type: "GET",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                if (data == true) {
                    $('#deleteservice-dlalog').dialog('open');
                }
                else {
                    $("#editform").submit();
                }
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. How many buttons do you have?

Comment: i have one save button

Comment: @maz3tt, I think if you call $('#editform').validate(); it will trigger the validation messages. So just call it first thing in your click handler.